# Can I get walking directions to lat,lon?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have a map of an outdoor arena with various pins plotted to designate points of interest. I would like to give walking directions to the selected pin. (just direction and distance primarily) Is that possible with the built-in frameworks?

Comment: Great... how do I do it?

Comment: How far have you got with trying it yourself? Looked at the MapKit docs, positioning annotations? CoreLocation? We're here to help, not write your code.

Comment: I'll take a look at the mkDirections noted below. I wasn't aware of that addition to iOS 7. Seems I can't know everything, thus the inquiry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into The `MKDirections` class. This is the apple provided class for getting directions. You can also integrate google's maps SDK. See the following links:

**UPDATE**: Added a link to a tutorial

http://www.devfright.com/mkdirections-tutorial/

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirections_class/Reference/Reference.html

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/